# Delete all data from apache solr core

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr4, inverted-index

I have apache solr setup(version 8.9) in windows system(standalone version), import and search functionality is working fine, however the delete all(complete cleanup) functionality seems to be not accurate.

i delete the data using below command(tried with both url and solr UI using request handler /update), its returning the success message.

`https://systemaName:8984/solr/app-core/update?{"delete":{"query":"*:*"}}&commit=true`

but when i actually check the core/data folder size still shows 6GB, same will be displayed in the dashboard

[image]

[image]

**How to reset/Delete complete data in apache solr core, so that we can import data from scratch.**

Comment: Have you called optimize on your index afterwards? `commit` and `deleteByQuery` will only mark those documents as deleted; the index will not be rewritten before a merge or an optimize happens.

Comment: I dint called the optimize on the index, I just called delete query and commit. I will try this approach, thanks for the directions.

Comment: You need to optimize the core